Combining alphas for mean variance optimizer
I have about 10 signals that I want to use to trade about 100 assets. I am using a mean variance optimizer that has a transaction cost penalty and enforces various portfolio constraints. I need to combine my signals in some way to get a combined signal,  which I can then pass to my portfolio optimization.
One way I can think of is to run some kind of rolling ridge regression of signals vs asset return. Or I could run another mean variance style optimization to get signal weights at each time step. Am I on the right track here? Or are there other ways how this is usually done?
The problem is that the restrictions and cost penalty might mean that some signals pass through the optimizer easier than others . Like I would imagine that highly leveraged signals that take large spread positions may have a much higher transfer coefficient than others. I am not sure if there is a good way to control for this or if I even should try to control it

Your approach seems feasible.
Here's what I would consider doing on similar hypotheses:

To combine signals for trading 100 assets, consider ridge regression or PCA to derive robust, linear combinations.

Use mean-variance optimization to manage transaction costs and enforce constraints effectively.

Adjust signals for risk factors and normalize for fair treatment.

Address signal scalability and transfer coefficients to mitigate bias.

Validate methods through cross-validation and robust out-of-sample testing to ensure performance across market conditions.

Iterate based on empirical results for strategy refinement and adaptability in real-world scenarios.


Hope it helps!
